# Excel Formula for A, B, C grouping and find first occurrences?

Tags: excel

I have this table like below:
[image]

The end result I want to achieve is:

- If there is One and only one group code in Column E, then the
  sub-group code should show only that value without A,B,C.
- If there are two group codes in column E, then the sub-group code
  should show groupcode A and groupcode B.
- If there are three group codes in column E, then the sub-group code should show groupcode A, groupcode B, and groupcode C.

========================================================================

Now as you can see in the table, I can only achieve 1003A (correct), but the second value should be 1003B instead of 1003C.

Here's my formula:

```
=IF(COUNTIF([Group Code],[@[Group Code]])=1, [@[Group Code]],
 IF(((COUNTIF($E$4:$E7,[@[Group Code]])=1)+0)=1, [@[Group Code]]&"A",
 IF(((COUNTIF($E$4:$E7,[@[Group Code]])=2)+0)=2, [@[Group Code]]&"B",
 [@[Group Code]]&"C")))
```

Anybody knows how do I tweak this code to produce the desirable result? 
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In F4 please try:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(E$4:E$8,E4)=1,E4,E4&CHAR(COUNTIF(E$4:E4,E4)+64))
```

[image: Table example]

Comment: `=IF(COUNTIF(E$4:E$8,E4)=1,E4&"",E4&CHAR(COUNTIF(E$4:E4,E4)+64))` keeps the sub-group code consistently text.

Comment: Maybe E$8 should be E8.